# Server response: 550 550 Verification failed for The mail server could not deliver mail (mailgun & compute-engine)

Tags: google-compute-engine, mailgun

when I send from  email01@mydomain.com  to email02@mydomain.com over smtp.mailgun.org I got this eroro:

"Failed: email01@mydomain.com → email02@mydomain.com 'RE: test mail' Server response: 550 550 Verification failed for  The mail server could not deliver mail to server_name. The account or domain may not exist, they may be blacklisted, or missing the proper dns entries. Sender verify failed"

but when I send from gmail.com to email02@mydomain.com 
or when I send from email02@mydomain.com to gmail.com

the mail sent and delivered success.

can you tell me why.

Note:
I'm using Google compute engine and WHM.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be directed at the support of the mail provider: https://www.mailgun.com/contact

Comment: I sent it to support. If I get answer I will share them to all. but to know I need to answer and other people need it. Share information to all if you have it.

Answer (score 1):

The error (which is called Sender Address Verification)

I go to

**WHM: Main >> Service Configuration >> Exim Configuration Editor >> Standard Options >> Mai**l

then put

**Sender Verification Callouts -> off
Sender Verification -> off**

Then everything is working fine.

Comment: Thanks. This really saved me a headache!